# Is jquery easyslider broken on IE8 and IE9 when you have images and content (div)?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, easyslider

I use easyslider and it works great in Firefox, IE 7 but in IE 8/9 the strangest thing is happening when i have content and an image.  The background images don't line up against the content that i have.

So if it have:

- Image 1 with content 1
- Image 2 with content 2
- Image 3 with content 3

Everything always lines up but in IE9, i see:

- Image 1 with content 2
- Image 2 with content 3
- Image 3 with content 1

When i change the browser to Compatibility Mode, it works fine again, but if I remove it then it goes back to the issue above.  Very weird.

Here is my css:

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .slider-container
    {
        width: 639px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: url(http://www.mysite.com/image.png) no-repeat -0px top transparent;
        height: 291px;
        padding: 2px 0 0 4px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .slider
    {
        width: 639px;
        height: 271px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    #slider
    {
        width: 639px;
        height: 271px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: -43px;
    }
```

Here is my html:

```
 <div class="slider-container">
    <div id="slider">
        <ul class="slider">

                 <li>
                    <img alt="" id="slide1" src="http://www.internationalnetworksolutions.net/images/1245854909_content_graphic_cost-savings.jpg" style="width: 639px; height: 271px" />
                    <div class="slider-content">
                        <p class="title">Title1</p>
                        <p class="text">Text1</a></p>
                    </div>
                </li>

                 <li>
                    <img alt="" id="slide2" src="http://media.treehugger.com/assets/images/2011/10/20081023-altamont-pass-wind-turbine.jpg" style="width: 639px; height: 271px" />
                    <div class="slider-content">
                        <p class="title">Title 2</p>
                        <p class="text">Text 2</a></p>
                    </div>
                </li>

                 <li>
                    <img alt="" id="slide5" src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/world-map-background.jpg" style="width: 639px; height: 271px" />
                    <div class="slider-content">
                        <p class="title">Title 3</p>
                        <p class="text">Text 3</a></p>
                    </div>
                </li>


        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add the slider-content style class in the post? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the DOCTYPE properly? Maybe:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Also I find this useful:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
```

Also remove the extra

```
</a>
```

in the slider contents...

What is otherwise the point in -0px on the background CSS?

Comment: what would be properly in this case?